# Synchronous & Asynchronous operation in same service?

Tags: web-services, soap

I am new to SOAP web services. My question is can we have two operations one of which is Synchronous & other one is Asynchronous in same web-service or to be precise in same WSDL. If yes then how can we do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can expose two port classes one for synchronous and another for asynchronous service.Synchronous service would be easy to implement and its direct.However for asynchronous you would need to design the class in such a way that once the request comes to the class create a id to track it and return the id  and submit the processing to a parallel thread with the id.In the thread execution pass relevant information so that at the end of the execution you can return the id as well the completed status .In this way you would be able to track the complete flow of the request.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. But I wanted to know how we can do it in WSDL

Comment: @AjaySharma You can create the service in java and follow a bottom up approach to create the WSDL from java. :)

Comment: I am sorry if I am not clear to you. But what I want to know is that ii there exists an attribute with which we can specify an operation inside WSDL to behave as Synchronous or assynchronous.